# Access Denied for User - MySQL Connector/ODBC

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I am in a class the involves using the MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver to connect to a database. When connecting to the database through a web interface I have no problems with my credentials. However, when trying to access the database via Visual Studio 2013 I receive an error.

First I will link the code that we are using to connect to the database

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
//Add namespaces needed for database connection
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;

//Project Lab #1
//By Jane Doe
//SAI 430 - Prof. Smith
//November 11, 2013

namespace ProjectLab1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Connection string needed to talk to Omnymbus
        string conString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};"
            + "Server=devry.edupe.net;Port=4300;"
            + "Database=Inventory_4264;"
            + "uid=4264;pwd=****";
        OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(conString);
        connection.Open();
        //Get all data
        string theQuery = "SELECT * FROM item";

        OdbcDataAdapter DataAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(theQuery, connection);
        DataSet theData = new DataSet();
        DataAdapter.Fill(theData, "item");
        DataTable theTable = theData.Tables[0];

        //Loop through all data results
        foreach (DataRow dataRow in theTable.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dataRow["item_id"].ToString());
        }

        connection.Close();  //Close connection

        //Have program pause to keep from closing console window
        Console.WriteLine("All Done - Press ENTER");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
 }
}
```

When executing this code I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a)
>   Driver]Access denied for user '4264'@'71.57.101.56' (using password:
>   YES)

I have tried connecting to the database directly via Administrative Tools > Data Sources but had no luck there either with the same error. I have tried using both 32 bit and 64 bit versions of the Connector as well with no difference in results. This is really giving me a difficult time and the instructor for the class is having a hard time offering any effective solution.

I appreciate any insight you folks can offer

Comment: If you cannot connect directly with Data Sources, why do you expect C# to be able to connect? Also, you shouldn't need to specify the driver in the connection string

Comment: `AccessDenied` ... I think the error speaks for itself. Your connection string is wrong in one way, shape, or form. That `uid` seems suspect as well.

Comment: It's not that I expect C# to be able to do it when Data Sources can't connect, I was just throwing the information in for context. The C# is pulled straight from instructions given in the class, and we just plug in the database, uid, and pwd fields. I know that these fields are valid because I can log in through the web interface that we used to actually create the tables in the database.

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when MySQL does not allow external connections.

The default accepts only connections from localhost.

The secure way to do this is to connect through a ssh tunnel (on Linux) and do a portforwarding. Otherwise you have to allow the user to connect from other devices too.

See here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

The remote connections are not recommended for security reasons!

Comment: I'm not surprised to hear that this isn't the ideal way to do things, but it's how the class seems to work. I am a student at DeVry and the whole point of this class is to get C#.net to talk to a relational database.Everyone in the class was given a username and password to plug into the connection string provided above and some people have had 0 issues while I am having difficulties in both the virtual environment provided by the school and my local environment on my laptop

Comment: Did you Check the Website?

Comment: I was able to log into the website they gave us: devry.edupe.net:8300 which is what let me know that the credentials I have work. I'm taking the class online so the instructor hasn't been too easy to get help from in regards to the issue, if he would even know how to deal with it. I have an appointment with a more seasoned instructor to get it looked at but the sooner I can get this done the sooner I can get my work started

Comment: This works, brause your webinterface is at the Same machine. So it uses localhost with your user to connect. You have to connect through ssh or you have to grant this user access from everywhere or your specific IP address. It will not work otherwise.